# Prometheus nested alert query in prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Can it b possible to add nested query in prometheus alerts?
I am using prometheus to monitor kubernetes cluster.

Alert is generated if node is down but i want to configure alert so that if any node is down then prometheus should not send alert for pods and services which are running on that.

Something like this,

```
if(pod_down)
  if(corresponding_node_down)
    //dont send alert
    //node down alert is in firing state
```

Answer (score 2):

If a node is down, then Kubernetes should be handling that automatically and moving services elsewhere. Accordingly an alert like this isn't very useful.

What I'd suggest you do it alert on user-visible symptoms such as high latency and error ratios rather than individual causes such as a machine or container being down.

Comment: can we use <inhibit_rule> incase of muting alerts which are not the reason for the cause?

example: if we have 3 services A, B, C ->  A is calling B , B is calling C, but something went wrong in C service and it is generating errors. so because of C, A and B also in bad state, obviously prometheus generates alerts for A and B as well. so with <inhibit_rule> can we able to mute alerts for A and B ?

Answer (score 2):

#### Inhibition

Take a look at this Prometheus Alertmanager configuration.

link: [prometheus.io/docs/alerting/configuration/#inhibit_rule](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/configuration/#%3Cinhibit_rule%3E)

> Inhibition is a concept of suppressing notifications for certain alerts if certain other alerts are already firing.
>
> Example: An alert is firing that informs that an entire cluster is not reachable. Alertmanager can be configured to mute all other alerts concerning this cluster if that particular alert is firing. This prevents notifications for hundreds or thousands of firing alerts that are unrelated to the actual issue.

reference: https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/alertmanager